# SPARQL result set limit of 10000

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I run a query that I know should return more than 10,000 rows against `Virtuoso` but I get only 10,000 rows back. I am not using a `LIMIT` clause at the end of my query. Is that number a default result set limit and how can it be overridden?

My query is:

```
select distinct ?s { ?s ?p ?o. }
```

Comment: You can increase the size only if it's your own maintained Virtuoso triple store via a config parameter in the virtuoso.ini file. Otherwise, `LIMIT n OFFSET m` aka pagination has to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is your own instance, you can edit the [`ResultSetMaxRows`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#ini_sparql_resultsetmaxrows) setting in the INI file.

If this is someone else's instance, they may be willing/able to adjust that setting.  If not, you can use `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` (and `ORDER BY`) clauses to step through the full result set.

Comment: in the meantime, i realized getting such a huge payload (1M+ triples) in one HTTP response might not be a good idea so I devised a batch breakdown using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` to continue where the previous iteration ended

Comment: Remember that without an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause, rows may be returned in any order, which may change with each `OFFSET`/`LIMIT` iteration, so leaving this out may mean you have duplicate and/or missing rows after the full page-through!

Comment: i was thinking about that.  in the above query, should I just do `ORDER BY ?s` ?

Comment: but I think that's not safe in case someone changes data while my process is running. is there a way to do greater than the last item from the previous batch ?  maybe that's a subject for a separate thread

Comment: or better yet, is it possible to order by the timestamp of each triple creation, if the server captures that data ?

Comment: It seems like you're feeling your way through some development. It might be worth sketching your overall goals, and asking for some "best practices" along those lines... potentially on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) if it's more Virtuoso-specific than SPARQL- or RDF-generic

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a default set by the service to limit users from unknowingly downloading the entire repository with a SPO query.